# How to convert cross apply from SQL Server query to Teradata query

Tags: sql-server, migration, teradata

I have a SQL Server query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS A 
INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.col1 = B.col1 
                       AND A.col2 = B.col2
CROSS APPLY TableC(B.col3) AS C;
```

How will I convert this query to a Teradata one?

Comment: What is `TableC(B.col3)`?  That is an odd name for a table valued function.

Comment: We can't give you a full answer without knowing what your TVF does. But in very general terms, you can probably replace your TVF with a CTE, window functions, etc.